# Why is the cv2 HOGDescriptor giving segmentation faults?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, segmentation-fault, detection

I'm working on improving the efficiency for the detection of humans in image frames. Instead of applying the HOG descriptor on the whole image, I plan to only use the HOG descriptor on extracted regions of interest (regions that have motion using a mask obtained from background subtraction).

When using detectMultiScale(...) from the HOG descriptor provided by OpenCV2, the program returns a segmentation fault (Python 2.7 and cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector() for the SVM). A lot of the extracted regions from the image are of different aspect ratios. Applying the HOG Descriptor on the whole image works fine but it segfaults on certain regions.

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why is this happening?
Are there restrictions on the width and height of the input images to the descriptor?

The documentation doesn't say anything about that http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/opencv-2.4.10-docs/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html

```
(rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(region, 
                                        winStride=(4, 4), 
                                        padding=(8, 8), 
                                        scale=1.05)
rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
pick = non_max_suppression(rects, probs=None, overlapThresh=0.65)
```

region is the image slice extracted from the original image. I thought about trying to catch the segmentation fault like one could catch an error ([How can I "catch" a seg fault while importing an F2Py module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929162/how-can-i-catch-a-seg-fault-while-importing-an-f2py-module)) but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Upload the image on which it fails. Upload a complete code to reproducible the same error. Add opencv version as well.